# CFSpreadSheet - format column not formatting the entire column

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

Using CF10 Standard to create a spreadsheet from a query.  No matter what I've tried so far, the formatting for a specific column stops at row 32 (1 header row, 31 data), even though the entire sheet is populated to 186 rows.

```
<cfscript>
 dfStyle=StructNew();
 dfStyle.fgcolor="pale_blue";
 dfStyle.dataformat="mm/dd/yyyy";
 theSheet = SpreadSheetNew('mysheet');
 SpreadSheetAddRow(theSheet,'SID,FIRST,LAST,ADDRESS1,ADDRESS2,CITY,STATE,ZIP,EMAIL,ADDED,PID');
 SpreadSheetAddRows(theSheet,qry);
 SpreadSheetFormatColumn(theSheet,dfStyle,10);
</cfscript>
```

I'm trying to get a consistent mm/dd/yyyy format on the 'ADDED' column.  Instead, I'm getting that through row 31, and then getting dates like 41937.56594 on the of the rows.

[image]

In the formula bar I show "10/20/2014  12:25:23 PM" as the first value and "41932.552037037" as the 2nd value.

If I format the date in the query (i.e. date_format(sp_add,'%c/%e/%Y') AS spadd) I do get a nice date format all the way down the column, but the blue still stops at row 32.

Here is the cfoutput of the anonymized query - top row is formatted, bottom row loses formatting (background color - formatting dates in query).  I also dropped the ADDRESS2 column from the query for now.

[image]

Comment: What are the values of that particular field for the last formatted and first unformatted rows?

Comment: Dan - I updated question to have a screen capture and values from the formula bar

Comment: I think you need to dump your query and check out the record from row 32. I think the date stored in the database is different from row 32 than earlier rows.

Comment: Tushar - that column is all datetimeformat in mysql.  Besides, if I use date_format in the query, the blue color still stops at the same row.

Comment: @DanBracuk - I'm with you - it has to be some piece of data. STeve, Do a raw output of the data (NOT cfdump - use cfoutput and view source). examine row 32 _and_ row 31 ... is there a piece of data in either than could screw up the cells? look at all the cells of data in the 2 rows - not just the date field.

Comment: @MarkAKruger - see above.  I used cfouput to output the query rows.  I changed up the names and addresses but that's exactly how it outputs from the query.  Line 43 (Smith) is formatted, but nothing after that is.

Comment: Ok I'm out of ideas at the moment. Let's try this - selection JUST your date column (ADDED) and create your spreadsheet without all the OTHER data?

Comment: Have you tried the xml format?  (xlsx) Modify your new command to `spreadsheetNew('Mysheet',true)` and see what happens. Under the hood it uses a different format.

Comment: @MarkAKruger - same thing - I get blue dates through row 42, and 43 and onward has no formatting.  This is just selecting the date column - nothing else. Just for fun I selected just the SID column (db autonumber), set the only formatting to fgcolor and it colors through row 43, but 44 and on has no formatting.  Honestly, I solved the initial issue with putting the date_format() in the query, but now it's just become some sort of erratic behavior witchhunt (which I'm willing to continue if you want me to try anything else)

Comment: Try the xml format... but it seems like a bug to me. I'll do a hunt in the bugbase.

Comment: I did a quick survey of reported bugs and I don't see anything like this. Just an FYI.

Comment: @MarkAKruger - XML format solved the problem!  Thank you for spotting that.

Comment: Great! I added it as a solution for others if you want to mark it.

Comment: Were you viewing the results in Office 365? I had this issue with an isolated user on Office 365 recently. In the end we opted to ignore the issue as a bug in Office 365 for other versions of office would display the date correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what the problem is, but try using the XML format option (the option to produce an xlsx file instead of the older style xls file). In your code add the "true" as a second argument to your spreadsheetnew() function call.

```
<cfscript>
 dfStyle=StructNew();
 dfStyle.fgcolor="pale_blue";
 dfStyle.dataformat="mm/dd/yyyy";

 theSheet = SpreadSheetNew('mysheet',TRUE);

 SpreadSheetAddRow(theSheet,'SID,FIRST,LAST,ADDRESS1,ADDRESS2,CITY,STATE,ZIP,EMAIL,ADDED,PID');
 SpreadSheetAddRows(theSheet,qry);
 SpreadSheetFormatColumn(theSheet,dfStyle,10);
</cfscript>
```

This will solve the problem - though we don't know why :)

Comment: Thant helped, thanks a lot.. crazy but yes it works.