# spreadsheetFormatRow stops formatting

Tags: coldfusion

I am creating a spreadsheet with CF10 and I am adding rows and then formatting them.
I am using `spreadsheetFormatRow` and it is working, but then it just stops formatting.  I cannot format after a certain point.  I am not sure what the issue is.

Such as this:

```
<cfset spreadsheetAddRow(variables.newsheet," ")>
<cfset spreadsheetAddRow(variables.newsheet,"Branch Activity")>
<cfset spreadsheetFormatRow(variables.newsheet,variables.formatstyle,'#variables.newsheet.RowCount#')>
<cfset spreadsheetAddRow(variables.newsheet,",Phone and Website Activity are Not Included in Branch Activity")>
<cfset spreadsheetAddRow(variables.newsheet,",Checkouts,Renewals,InHouse,Discharges")>
<cfset spreadsheetFormatRow(variables.newsheet,variables.formatheaders,'#variables.newsheet.RowCount#')>
```

If I add more rows and try to format them it doesn't work, but it does here.  Is there some limit or syntax that can throw this off?

Comment: Do you work with this guy?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26657086/cfspreadsheet-format-column-not-formatting-the-entire-column

Comment: @DannyC - I would suggest formatting a range of rows - rather than individual ones. Excel itself has limitations on the total number of styles you can apply. Using `SpreadsheetFormatRows` may generate less styles overall, which *might* solve the issue. If not, the other poster said switching to xmlformat solved his issue. Can you try that? Also, out of curiosity - what is your exact version? The reason I ask is I tested their code with 200 rows and it worked fine under CF10 (no patches). Just wondering if it is a bug introduced in a later version or an issue related to the actual data.