# SpreadsheetFormatRow abruptly stops working

Tags: coldfusion, spreadsheet, coldfusion-10, cfspreadsheet

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26660630/spreadsheetformatrow-stops-formatting) post, but there does look to be a resolution.  Anyway, I'm using ColdFusion 10 to generate an Excel spreadsheet.  However, when I use SpreadsheetFormatRow() and pass in the rows to be formatted, it only does about 3 and then abruptly stops.  Here is an example...

**ColdFusion Code**

```
<cfscript>

    rowCount = 1;
    headingRows = 4;

    // Create instance of new Spreadsheet
    excelSheet = SpreadsheetNew("ReportName",false); 

    // HEADING (IMAGE) ROW FORMAT
    formatHeadingRow = StructNew();
    formatHeadingRow.fgcolor="blue";        

    // Add rows to fill the header area (must add as many as we are spanning with the above image)
    for (x=0;x<headingRows;x++) {
        SpreadsheetAddRow(excelSheet,"TEST,TEST,TEST,TEST,TEST,TEST,TEST,TEST,TEST,TEST,TEST,TEST");
        SpreadsheetFormatRow(excelSheet,formatHeadingRow,rowCount);
        rowCount++;
    }

</cfscript>

<!--- stream it to the browser --->
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="inline; filename=reportName.xls">
<cfcontent type="application/vnd.ms-excel" variable="#SpreadSheetReadBinary(excelSheet)#">
```

**and here is a screenshot of the resulting Excel sheet**

[image]

Why is the formatting stopping after X number of rows and cells?
If I switch to using XML format with

```
excelSheet = SpreadsheetNew("ReportName",true);
```

it works properly.  However I'm using a custom palette for my colors so I don't think switching to XLSX format is going to work for me.  When I try and then call

```
palette = excelSheet.getWorkbook().getCustomPalette();
```

I get an error stating that getCustomPalette() method is undefined.

```
coldfusion.runtime.java.MethodSelectionException: The getcustompalette method was not found
```

Can anyone help me figure this out?  Thank you!!!

Or even better since it works with the XML format, can anyone show example of how to use a custom palette with the XLSX (xml format)

Comment: Just tried your code via trycf and it works fine on cf10 http://trycf.com/gist/ce1e66bed5fe5d1bc40f8abd79f8fc72/acf?theme=monokai

Comment: @JohnWhish I just tried using your trycf.com link and it gave me the same results.  Broken formatting after a few rows, with the last few cells left white instead of blue.  What version of Excel?  Mine is Excel 2016 with Office 365

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue I have seen often when dealing with xls files from CF; they seem to stop applying styles after a certain number of cells. I've been able to work around it by outputting to xlsx instead. (I was able to replicate and "fix" your issue by doing so.)

```
excelSheet = SpreadsheetNew("ReportName",true);
```

...

```
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="inline; filename=reportName.xlsx">
<cfcontent type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
        variable="#SpreadSheetReadBinary(excelSheet)#">
```

Comment: while this does work, I need to use a custompalette with my spreadsheet so I'm not limited to the HSSF predefined colors.  When I try to use the XLSL option, the getCustomPalette() method is no longer available in the workbook object.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are applying the exact same format to all rows, only do it *once*, not on each row. Using [SpreadsheetFormatCellRange](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-s/spreadsheetformatcellrange.html) after the loop should resolve the issue:

```
SpreadsheetFormatCellRange(excelSheet
                             , formatHeadingRow
                              , startRow
                              , startCol
                              , endRow
                              , endCol );
```

I *suspect* the problem somehow relates back to [Excel's maximum style limits](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/213904). Since CF is a black box, it is difficult to know how many styles it actually creates or exactly how they are applied. However, in my experience it is very easy to exceed the style limits without even knowing it. Especially when using the older .xls file format, whose limits are much lower. That is why I suggested [using the newer .xlsx format instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26660630/spreadsheetformatrow-stops-formatting#comment41923881_26660630).

> getCustomPalette() method is undefined.

Correct. It does not exist in XSSF. Is there some reason you need a custom palette instead of just [defining your own colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37727645/spreadsheetformatrows-format-color-coldfusion), as mentioned in your other thread?

Comment: implementing the example you provided on my other post to get my custom colors, and switching over to the XSLX format.

Comment: In fairness, if you are going to switch to xlsx, @TimJasko suggested that first :)  While the above does solve the problem for .xls, honestly it is only prolonging the inevitable as far as styles are concerned. The better option is to switch to .xlsx, which has more functionality and higher style limits.