# How to show full number in Excel sheet?

Tags: coldfusion, cfspreadsheet

I'm exporting a query to an Excel file using cfspeadsheet. It's working and creating the Excel sheet. However, the problem is that one of the columns, ie `card_number`, contains a 15 digit number, which is displayed like this: `4.5421E+15`. Is there a way I can display the full number instead: `4254218068670980` ?

```
<!--- create manual query for demo --->
<cfset qData = queryNew("")>
<cfset queryAddColumn(qData, "NumericCol", "BigInt",["4254218068670980"])>
<cfset queryAddColumn(qData, "StringCol", "Varchar",["4254218068670980"])>
<cfset queryAddColumn(qData, "DecimalCol", "Decimal",["4254218068670980"])>

<!--- export to file --->
<cfspreadsheet action="write" 
        filename="c:/path/to/myFile.xls"
        query="qData" 
        overwrite="true">
```

Comment: I REALLY hope that is not a credit card number ....  ;-)

Comment: nope ramdom number , i can change it too in cause of any confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define and use a format for the cell to show complete number. Below is a sample code snippet for your code:

```
<cfscript> 
theFile=GetDirectoryFromPath(GetCurrentTemplatePath()) & "new_data.xls"; 
//Create a new Excel spreadsheet object. 
theSheet = SpreadsheetNew("Expenses"); 
//Set the value a cell. 
SpreadsheetSetCellValue(theSheet,"4254218068670980",1,4);
//Set value into another cell. 
SpreadsheetSetCellValue(theSheet,"4254218068670980",2,4);
// Define a format class for for number. 
longNum=StructNew(); 
longNum.dataformat = "0"; 
//Now use this class to format cell 
SpreadsheetFormatCell(theSheet,longNum,2,4); 
</cfscript>
```

There are many supported formats available; for a complete list you may check [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-s/spreadsheetformatcell.html).
Also, just like [SpreadsheetFormatCell](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-s/spreadsheetformatcell.html) you may want to use [SpreadsheetFormatColumn](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-s/spreadsheetformatcolumn.html) or other related functions.

Comment: You'll need to format the cell before filling it with data. I also noticed that the amount of cells and rows you can format in this way is limited to 4000, but I haven't found a way around that yet.
Which is why we use Ben Nadel's POI custom tags, which you can find [here](https://github.com/bennadel/POIUtility.cfc).

Comment: @Sander - Most likely it is caused by formatting cells individually. [Excel limits the number of "styles" you can apply](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37817997/spreadsheetformatrow-abruptly-stops-working/37820034#37820034). The limits are lower for .xls than .xlsx. Usually the solution is to apply formats once - to a range or an entire column - instead of individually.

Answer (score 1):

(Too long for comments...)

FWIW, CFSpreadsheet is designed for very simple exports, without a lot of bells and whistles. If you need special formatting, you must use spreadsheet functions instead.

The closest equivalent to your current code is probably the [SpreadsheetAddRows(sheet, query)](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-s/spreadsheetaddrows.html) function. It populates a worksheet with the data in the supplied query object. As [Viv's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39091209/104223) mentions, you can then format the columns as desired. For example, if you want the value to be treated as text, use `{dataformat = "@"}`:

```
<cfscript>
   SpreadsheetAddRows(theSheet, qData); 
   SpreadsheetFormatColumns(theSheet, {dataformat = "@"}, "1-3"); 
   SpreadSheetWrite(theSheet, "c:/path/to/myFile.xls", true);
</cfscript>
```

As an aside, the examples in the documentation are not always the best or cleanest. Consider them a starting point, rather than using the code exactly "as is" ..